# Change ROOTDRIVE and DIRPROPERTY values for an MSI in InstallShield 2016 if Target Drive Doesn't Exist

Tags: if-statement, properties, scripting, installshield

I have an MSI I've put together in InstallShield, the default values for the two properties are ROOTDRIVE = D: | DIRPROPERTY1 = D:\

What I'm trying to achieve is on install if the drive isn't found redirect/revert to C: & C:\

I tried using a custom action but I wasnt to good at applying it.

Answer (score 0):

In VBScript, try using following method to set directory with your own logic of drive not found:

Session.TargetPath("INSTALLDIR") = custom value

Also, make sure to schedule this custom action after CostFinalize standard action.